# Performance Implications to Using a Full Class A Subnet

Tags: networking, subnet

Let's say you have a small network (50-60 IPs) and assign everything a 10.x.x.x IP with a subnet of 255.0.0.0. This gives you a huge range of usable IPs. What performance implications will this have on the network if any?

Comment: The potential for problems comes from the number of actual hosts, not the number of potential hosts. If you have 50-60 hosts/devices it doesn't matter if your subnet mask is /8, /16, /24 or anything else. You'll have 50-60 hosts worth of traffic.

Comment: FYI, the concept of classful networks went away in the early 1990s with the advent of CIDR.  Avoid using "class A" in favor of something like "/8" or "netmask 255.0.0.0"

Comment: Classful network never went away....
Many large ISPs and corporations still own public IP class blocks. Just because CIDR allows you to be more specific when speaking of internal networks doesn't mean class networks stopped being a thing across all parts of the industry.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say you have a small network (50-60 IPs) and assign everything a 10.x.x.x IP with a subnet of 255.0.0.0. This gives you a huge range of usable IPs. What performance implications will this have on the network if any?

For one, you're leaving yourself wide open to ARP attacks and resource exhaustion on your edge router.  A /8 subnet can potentially host over 16 Million IP addresses.  If some miscreant decided to spoof gratuitous ARPs across that entire range of addresses to your router, the router could easily be crushed under the load of maintaining that ARP table.  ARP is an unauthenticated protocol; by default, routers have no choice but to cache (and then attempt to re-ARP upon timeout) all the ARPs they receive.  Both memory and CPU are a concern in this situation.  You should implement [ARP Inspection](http://packetpushers.net/yes-we-really-need-dynamic-arp-inspection/) if you really want to use a /8, but you shouldn't need to in most cases.

HBruijn's comment about broadcast volume is not unfounded, although broadcast traffic tends to be specific to the type of hosts on the network; for instance, windows hosts or hosts running an SMB protocol tend to source more broadcasts.  However, I have seen relatively small /24 subnets get hammered by broadcast traffic simply because some coder decided to use broadcast instead of multicast for their high-bandwidth protocol.

Comment: Broadcasts have no different effect on 50 hosts in 10.0.0.0/8 than it does on 50 hosts in 10.0.0.0/24.  Refer to @joeqwerty's comment about number of hosts versus potential hosts.  Broadcasts are flooded out all active switch interfaces in the subnet, regardless of subnet size.